# Is thera a program to crack hashes for MD5?

Tags: software-rec

In Linux, it is possible to put the program to find a string containing letters a-z and whose MD5-hash is known? How can I do that if I estimate the running time will be about 40 days if computer is running all the time and I would like to save current computation as I have no ability to keep my computer running nightly? The problem is from https://www.ohjelmointiputka.net/postit/tehtava.php?tunnus=md5h

Comment: It doesn't say if all words are random or if they are from a list, but judging by the number of passwords that people have successfully cracked, it's randomized.

Answer (score 2):

1. John the Ripper password cracker, https://www.openwall.com/john/
2. HashCat, https://hashcat.net/hashcat/
3. Google and wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_cracking